# How to change location of index.js

Tags: npm

I'm trying to re arrange a project repo from this:

```
public/
src/
|
|---- index.js
package.json
```

To this:

```
public/
frontend/
|
|---- src/
      |
      |---- index.js
package.json
```

When I rearranged, `npm start` would fail with this message:

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/Sentify/src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Sentify@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Sentify@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

So I went into the package.json file and added this:

```
"main": "frontend/src/index.js",
```

What's strange is that nothing changes. npm tells me that it's still looking in the same directory for `index.js`.

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/Sentify/src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sentify@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sentify@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How can I successfully rearrange my project into this organisation? How can I tell npm where to look for index.js?

I also tried:

```
"main": "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/DH2642/Sentify/repo/Sentify/Sentify/frontend/src/index.js",
```

Comment: What path did you have before in `main` ? Was it working then ?

Comment: It was not defined in package.json. It was working fine. Also, restoring the original file hierarchy but keepin my "main" field in package.json for the new file hierarchy doesn't result in a crash. The "main" field is ignored and everything works fine again :/

Comment: What OS are you running on ? Mac ? Have you tried with `"./frontend/src/index.js"` ?

Comment: yes, Mac. I tried that, same thing. npm is completely ignoring the `"main"` field in package.json